# javascript bound to a button inside a form created using ajax not firing

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

so an html form is created dynamically using ajax. inside the html form there's a button which has it's onclick event bound to some javascript. the javascript is fired successfully in FF, Opera, IE but not in chrome where nothing happens. Any idea what the problem might be??

```
    <div id="s">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="reply" onclick="comment()"/>
    </div>


    function comment()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("post","replyForm.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

    }

function remove() {
var xmlhttpp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttpp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttpp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttpp.open("post","replyButton.php",true);
xmlhttpp.send();

xmlhttpp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttpp.readyState==4 && xmlhttpp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=xmlhttpp.responseText;
    }
}

    }
```

replyForm.php

```
    <?php
    echo("<script type='text/javascript' src='validation.js'></script>");
    echo("<input type=SUBMIT name=INS value='Submit' class='button' /> <input type='button' class ='button' value='Cancel' onclick=\"remove()\"/> <INPUT TYPE=RESET NAME=RES VALUE='Clear' class='button' />");
    ?>
```

replyButton.php

```
    <?php
    echo("<script type='text/javascript' src='validation.js'></script>");
    echo("<input type='button' class='button' value='reply' onclick='comment()'>");
    ?>
```

Comment: Post your code, we're not mind readers.

Comment: paste the javascript and generated form code, or anything that might make us understand the problem more, please.

Comment: And check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309895/why-doesnt-ajax-beginform-work-in-chrome

Comment: the thing which was causing problem was the name of the javascript function : remove()
it works as it should in chrome also if i change the name form remove to something else. don't know why it creates problems with chrome and not with any other browser i tested the code with (FF, Opera, IE, Safari, Torch)
 http://www.webmasterworld.com/google_chrome/4536702.htm

Comment: http://blog.socialcast.com/jquery-custom-remove-event-with-chrome-24/

Answer (score 0):

As the page is dynamically created. The event handlers are not assigned to the buttons or any elements.

use `bind()`  to bind the event handler to the element. This should be used instead of the normal click event handler

[Bind tutorial](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)